# Unable to use 'jsonpath' within Apache Karaf with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jsonpath

I am unable to get the below route activated within Apache Karaf.

```
from("file:/home/data/test?delete=true")
        //See https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath
        .split().jsonpath("$.[*]") //get all the array elements
            .setHeader("targetport").jsonpath("$.targetport") //Set the value of target port in header
                .transform().jsonpath("$.payload") //Content Filter EIP
                    //.toF("netty4:tcp://%s:%s?sync=false&workerCount=1&encoding=UTF-8&&encoders=#bypass-message-encoder", , );
                    .toD("netty4:tcp://1.1.1.1:${in.header[targetport]}?sync=false&workerCount=1&encoding=UTF-8&&encoders=#bypass-message-encoder");
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> Split[jsonpath{$.[*]} -> [SetHeader[targetport, jsonpath{$.targetport}], Transform[{}], DynamicRouter[bean{org.snog.testing.camelcontext.route.TcpEndPointCreater, method=dynamicRoute}]]] <<< in route: Route(route2)[[From[file:/home/snog/data/test?delete=true]] ... because of No language could be found for: jsonpath
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1028)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2895)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2618)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchLanguageException: No language could be found for: jsonpath
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultLanguageResolver.noSpecificLanguageFound(DefaultLanguageResolver.java:101)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultLanguageResolver.resolveLanguage(DefaultLanguageResolver.java:80)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolveLanguage(DefaultCamelContext.java:1898)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
        at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.createExpression(ExpressionDefinition.java:178)[54:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.2]
```

Information:

```
Apache Karaf: 4.0.3

Commands Issued:

 - feature:repo-add camel 2.15.2
 - feature:install camel-jsonpath
 - feature:install camel-netty4
```

Have tried with Apache Camel 2.16.1 too. Same error

My search for similar error have resulted in following, and none of them seem to help

- [CAMEL-6060 related to mvel](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6060)
- [JSON Splitter in Forum](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Json-Splitter-td5764739.html)

Comment: did you install the required features?

Comment: did you see the features and bundles as installed when viewed in Karaf?

Comment: Yes, I checked twice. Bundles were there.

Comment: how do you run camel in karaf, eg how do you get it bootstrapped ?